# rundeck - Jenkins integration plugin not working as option provider

Tags: maven, jenkins, rundeck

I am using the following plugin to get job options in rundeck.

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/RunDeck+Plugin

Plugin is already installed in jenkins. But when I am opening the corresponding URL:

[http://JENKINS_HOST/plugin/rundeck/options/build?project='jobname'&artifactRegex=.*.jar&limit=5&includeLastSuccessfulBuild=true&includeLastStableBuild=true](http://JENKINS_HOST/plugin/rundeck/options/build?project='jobname'&artifactRegex=.*%5C.jar&limit=5&includeLastSuccessfulBuild=true&includeLastStableBuild=true)

in browser, I am getting following error:

```
Status Code: 400
Exception: You must provide a valid 'project' parameter !
```

Not sure what is the issue. The project name given in the URL is correct and it is an existing Jon in Jenkins.